# Fix markdown tables with prettier

Tags: markdown, prettier

Can I somehow fix broken tables in markdown by running prettier?
For example
input:

```
+--------+
|text |
+--------+
```

output:

```
+--------+
|text    |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Prettier [formats](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAdKAFAlgGwjAHwEEsAnABwlMIAkIBXUgZ3QFpWCl2kDv0ApCAAsoAAgAiEOAQDKAaQDiBAIwBmVQA4BAQyhxRAJSkF+AMTkFVygCzoQAGhARyMLNCbJQ20qQgB3DG8EDxRtHD9tAE8PRwAjUm0wAGs4GBlyRKwoAHNkGFJ6OEc4AFtYuAATCsqAGV1s+m1suFMqEu0YVxzkEG16GAgHECEYEpwAdSEseCYMsDgZYOmsADdpyJ6wJhiQLKY4agwE7PbkADMw-ccAKyYADwAhBOTUmW0SuBqsuHPLopBbncZFlsjg4ABFej4H5IC44K4gDLMA49dqkJIVfxQIbkUhZGDjLAVGBCZAaAAMjlxEH24wS5B6uLg+1IKx+jgAjlD4EdnCFekxWHpKpUhqQ4FyyHAjk1TrC-o59iUsHkCv8mCCwZDob94f8YNpYoTiaSkAAmRz5bS4EEAYQgJTlIGZAFYhvR9gAVQ0hOEIlaFACSUGqsBkYDxLiIIZkMEiYN1+wAvkmgA) tables in Markdown, but your example is not a Markdown table. Here's what the syntax for tables usually looks like in Markdown dialects that support it (e.g., in [GitHub-flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-)):

```
| Pilot    | Airport | Hours |
| -------- | :-----: | ----: |
| John Doe |   SKG   |  1338 |
| Jane Roe |   JFK   |   314 |
```

StackOverflow supports that syntax too:

| Pilot | Airport | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | SKG | 1338 |
| Jane Roe | JFK | 314 |

But not yours:

+--------+
|text |
+--------+